# Force users to sign out in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an app where users have a membership that expires.

I'm working on setting up a `before_filter` in my `applications.rb` file to check that they're membership is active prior to letting them in the site.

In my application.rb file:

```
before_filter :check_account

def check_account
  if user_signed_in?
     if current_user.account.expired
       flash[:error] = "Your account is expired. Please contact Navanti for renewal."
       redirect_to destroy_user_session_path
     end
  end
end
```

I keep getting a redirect loop error. I'm guessing that it's because of the logout page that's being called is also doing the `before_filter`, but if I put an `except => [:users => :sign_out]` it still throws the loop error.

Thanks for the help.

---

Requested Devise Method:

```
# DELETE /resource/sign_out

def destroy
  redirect_path = after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name)
  signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
  set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_navigational_format?  

  # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
  # support returning empty response on GET request
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    format.all do
      head :no_content
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Write the code for destroy_user_session_path.

Comment: yes plz put destroy code here

Comment: That code is coming from the Devise gem - I'll try to find it and add it to the question.

Comment: I added the code - but this is found in the gem and I really rather not edit it. I'm thinking it has something to do with the filter and the right way to call it.

Comment: I think you would be better off preventing them from logging in entirely than by kicking them out immediately after logging in. See [this HOWTO](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) for the basic pattern.

Comment: @willglynn - great solution. I'm working on implementing that now - much smoother fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try querying the controller/action the following way:

```
def check_account
  return if params[:controller] == "devise/sessions" && params[:action] == "destroy"
  if user_signed_in?
     if current_user.account.expired
       flash[:error] = "Your account is expired. Please contact Navanti for renewal."
       redirect_to destroy_user_session_path
     end
  end
end
```

This should eliminate the redirection loop you're having.

Comment: Thanks Erez - that worked great. I have a follow-up issue I'm noticing but will put that in another question.